# MS SQL query didn't work with PHP

Tags: php, sql-server

The following MS SQL query works fine in MS SQL Management Studio but not with PHP. I didn't get any error, but the `mssql_num_rows` return 0.

Query:

```
SELECT 
    S.LS, 
    S.IstWADatum, 
    S.Gesamtmenge, 
    SUM(T.Gesamtmenge) as GesamtmengeT, 
    SUM(PP.Gesamtmenge) as GesamtmengePP 
FROM 
    dbo.SAPREPORT AS S 
LEFT JOIN dbo.TRACE AS T 
    ON S.LS = T.LSNR 
LEFT JOIN dbo.PKSPLUS AS PP 
    ON S.LS = PP.LSNR 
WHERE 
    (S.Warenempfaenger = '1' 
    OR S.Warenempfaenger = '2' 
    OR S.Warenempfaenger = '3' 
    OR S.Warenempfaenger = '4' 
    OR S.Warenempfaenger = '5' ) 
    AND S.IstWADatum = '12.03.2015' 
GROUP BY 
    S.LS, 
    S.IstWADatum, 
    S.Gesamtmenge
```

The resultset in Studio is

`LS    IstWADatum  Gesamtmenge GesamtmengeT    GesamtmengePP
xxx     2015-03-12  14          NULL            NULL
xxx     2015-03-12  1           NULL            NULL
xxx     2015-03-12  4           NULL            NULL
xxx     2015-03-12  4           NULL            NULL
xxx     2015-03-12  5           NULL            NULL
xxx     2015-03-12  23          NULL            NULL
xxx     2015-03-12  43          NULL            NULL`

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us all the PHP code used to run the query, from getting the connection all the way to checking the results?

Comment: And how do you execute that query in php?

Comment: i bet your date gets wrong. convert it with `CONVERT(DateTime,'12.03.2105', 104)`

Comment: Thanks  A ツ! I tried with convert(varchar,getdate(),23)... Works fine now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution

```
AND S.IstWADatum = CONVERT(DateTime,'12.03.2105', 104)
```

Thanks to [A ツ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4579733/a-%E3%83%84)